# Show modal with message in Codigniter view

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble passing a message from the controller to show it in the view using a modal window using Codeigniter (I would like to show a modal with success/error message after an insert).

In the controller, I create a session using flashdata:

```
    $mensaje='OK';
    $this->session->set_flashdata('mensaje', 'OK');
```

In the view, I need to open the modal but I don´t know how to do it from php:

```
 <?php
         $mensaje='';
         $mensaje = $this->session->flashdata('mensaje');
         if($mensaje='OK'){
            // Here i need to open de modal window              
                                }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
$this->load->library('session');

$array_items = 
    array(
        'mensaje' => 'OK'
    );

$this->session->set_userdata($array_items);
$this->load->view('View_name');
```

In view

```
<?php

    $mensaje = $this->session->userdata('mensaje');
    if($mensaje=='OK')
    {
        ?>
        <!--        Load model here-->
    <?php
    }
?>
```

[CodeIgniter Session Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)